# Nifi install using Docker - Can´t access the webserver

Tags: docker, apache-nifi

I'm new to both docker and Nifi, I found this command that installs via docker and used it on a virtual machine that I have in GCP but I would like to access this container via webserver. In docker ps this appears to me:

[image]

What command do I need to execute to gain access to the tool via port 8080?

Comment: The container has already exposed port 8080 on the host. Navigate to `http://SERVER_ADDRESS:8080/` using your web browser

Comment: I am using a google virtual machine. I will check if port 8080 is released in the firewall rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container has already exposed port 8080 on the host, as evidence by the output `0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp`. You read that as `{HOST_INTERFACE}:{HOST_PORT}->{CONTAINER_PORT}/{PROTOCOL}`.

Navigate to `http://SERVER_ADDRESS:8080/` (or maybe `http://SERVER_ADDRESS:8080/nifi`) using your web browser. You may need to modify the firewall rules applied to your VM to ensure that you can access that port from your local machine.